# Failed to execute a script shell with node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, docker

I am trying to execute a script shell with node.js using a child process

initiateShipment.js

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
execFile('/home/nadhem/TradeFinance/Backend/SmartContract/initiateShipment.sh', 

(err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    return err;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

initiateShipment.sh

```
docker exec -i cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.fte.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/fte.com/orderers/orderer.fte.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.fte.com-cert.pem -C tradechannel -n tradefinancecc -c '{"Args":["initiateShipment","FTE_2"]}'
```

I am getting this error when executing

```
{ Error: Command failed: /home/nadhem/TradeFinance/Backend/SmartContract/initiateShipment.sh
the input device is not a TTY

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/home/nadhem/TradeFinance/Backend/SmartContract/initiateShipment.sh' }
```

NB:When I execute this script in the terminal it works correctly

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Tell us what you tried. Describe your problem and tell us how you tried to solve it. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If error message tells you that input device is not a TTY, why don't try to launch it with `-d` option instead `-i`?

Comment: I have the same error with -d or -i or -it